Matrix: Show Date Field in Card View
I would like to know if it is possible to display a custom date field in the card view of matrix field.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to use a date field as a title or part of a title. it gives:
Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string


It's not completely clear to me what you're trying to do, but to answer part of your question:
To include a Date field in entry titles, you'll have to convert it to a string – i.e. format it, for example
{heading} - {dateFieldHandle|date('Y-m-d')}

